# A Different Type of a "Measurement" Process?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-interpretations, foundations

In my understanding, a measurement process for the measurement of an observable $\hat{A}=\sum_i a_i\vert a_i\rangle\langle a_i\vert$ over a system that lives in $\mathcal{H}_1$ (when unentangled) by a measurement device that lives in $\mathcal{H}_2$ (when unentangled) is a process wherein the time-evolution operator $\hat{U}$ of on the full Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2$ is such that $\exists\vert\mathcal{R}\rangle\in\mathcal{H}_2$ and $\exists T>0$ such that

- $\hat{U}_T\Big(\vert a_i\rangle\otimes\vert \mathcal{R}\rangle\Big) = \vert a_i\rangle\otimes\vert b_i\rangle$

where $\langle b_i\vert b_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$. See, for example, equation $(1)$ in [Translation of "Die Messung quantenmechanischer Operatoren" by E.P. Wigner](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4372).

In standard quantum mechanics, this is the only type of process that can be said to be a measurement process given the explicit postulate(s) about the collapse of the state vector. In particular, if I measure a spin $1/2$ particle who is in a spin-up state along the $z$ axis, let's say, then the measurement of the spin in the $z$ direction, by definition, collapses the state onto, well, the same state and the measurement device displays the result that the spin is up. This fixes that the measurement process ought to be described by an evolution of the type that is written above.

However, in Everettean quantum mechanics, we don't have a conception of measurement beforehand. We look for processes that reproduce the kind of behavior described above simply from the dynamical evolution of the combined state of the particle and the measurement device. In other words, in Everettean quantum mechanics, we *discover* that there are these processes that will have this character of being qualified as the postulated measurement processes of standard quantum mechanics.  Now, it's natural to ask if there are other types of processes to be found in Everettean quantum mechanics that do the essential job of a measurement process but do not conform to the postulated measurement process of the standard quantum mechanics, i.e., tell us that the measured state has the value $a$ for observable $\hat{A}$ if the measured state is an eigenstate $\vert a\rangle$ -- but, they potentially result in an altered the post-measurement state of the system being measured. In particular, for example, one can consider

- $\hat{U}_T\Big(\vert a_i\rangle\otimes\vert \mathcal{R}\rangle\Big) = \hat{V}\vert a_i\rangle\otimes\vert b_i\rangle$

where $\hat{V}$ is a unitary operator acting on $\mathcal{H}_1$. Whether to call this a measurement or not might be a matter of linguistics but what is important is that it seems that such a process can be used to *obtain the same information* about a given system that a standard measurement process does, but unlike the standard measurement process, it collapses the measured system to a state that is potentially different than the eigenstate corresponding to the measured eigenvalue.

- Is there an argument to be made that such a process can only be consistent with unitarity and linearity if $\hat{V}=\hat{I}$ and thus, is just a standard measurement process?
- If not, are such processes physically interesting, and can they indeed be used to extract the same information about a system that a standard measurement can be used to do?
- Would the Born rule be reproduced for such a process when it is performed over a state that is not an eigenstate of the considered operator?

---

**Footnote**

Of course, such a process cannot "self-verify" that what it says to have "measured" is indeed correct because it alters the measured state even if it is an eigenstate of the observable being measured. However, it can be externally verified that such a process is a reliable means to extract the said information by preparing states in known eigenvalues of the observable (via standard procedure) and confirming that such a process gives the correct answers for what eigenvalue the measured state corresponded to even if it alters that state during the process.