# Von Neumann measurement - the only reasonable way to describe a measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, quantum-measurements, decoherence

*Introductory thoughts:* In many books on quantum mechanics, the Von Neumann measurement process (where the measurement device is modeled quantum mechanically) is described. For example by Schlosshauer (ISBN: 978-3540357735) in "Decoherence and the Quantum-To-Classical Transition" on page 51 and following (which I am referring to especially with this question).

*My goal:* I want to deduce that environment-induced decoherence can be seen as a measurement process. Therefore I need to describe the premeasurement (as it is often called) within the Von Neumann measurement process. To make my point clear, I need to establish the characteristics of the measurement process from requirements for the measurement (e.g. that it should not change the state of the system and that one can learn about the state of the system by looking at the measurement device).

*Question:* Is the characterization of the measurement process as seen in the Von Neumann measurement unique? - will the requirements always lead to this kind of characterization? It seems like this is an important question, although none of the books I looked into seemed to state this. I would therefore also appreciate hints on literature stating that.

Comment: can you provide complete reference to Schlosshauer?  Also do you consider generalized measurements (aka POVMs) as different from von Neumann’s?

Comment: I have so far not heard of POVMs. Therefore I am tended to say yes. It would be interesting if it made a difference if I didn't. Thank you for your question!

Comment: see for instance https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.07968.pdf as any number of starting points.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/662387/a-different-type-of-a-measurement-process